# SaveChangesAsync does not have expected performance improvement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I am comparing performances when awaiting tasks one by one, and when awaiting all task at once. My test results:

When loop count is 100

- await in the loop - 11595 ms
- await when all - 118 ms

wait when all is 98 times faster

When looping 1000 times

- await in the loop - 111249 ms
- await when all - 189

wait when all is 588 times faster.

I must say that something like this I have expected.

This is the code I have used for testing from the console application:

```
   public class TestSaveChanges
        {
            public async Task TestManySaves()
            {
                var loopCount = 100;
                var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                {
                    await TestSave();

                }
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                {
                    tasks.Add(TestSave());

                }
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            private async Task<bool> TestSave()
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Next step is to test the same scenario but with real save to DB. 
I just replace TestSave method with a new one.

```
private async Task<bool> TestSave()
{
    using (var db = new BloggingContext())
    {
        var blog = new Blog { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
        db.Blogs.Add(blog);
        var res = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return res != 0;
    }
}
```

I didn't expect the same improvements as with Task.Delay, but I hoped to see growing improvements with loops count.

I have got unexpected results for me.

When loop count is 100

- await in the loop - 9040 ms
- await when all - 582 ms

15 times faster

When loop count is 1000

- await in the loop - 10539 ms
- await when all - 4042 ms

2,6 times faster

When loop count is 3000

- await in the loop - 18786 ms
- await when all - 12992 ms

1,4 times faster

Probably for loop count 100 000 it is barely faster.
Why is this case? Can I somehow keep good performances even when loop count is huge?

Comment: You're seeing [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: By parallelizing, you minimized some inefficiency -- likely latency. But you've now run into a throughput issue.

Comment: You are likely hitting max connection pool limit, which is 100 by default. Try to set `Max Pool Size=1000` in connection string and observe the result again (not that I ever recommend to do this in practice...). Of course it will still not scale linearly anyway, since your database can only process so much insert operations to the same table (and in general) in given timeframe.

Comment: @Evk I don't see any significant change when I test with Max Pool Size=1000. If pool limit is 100, doesn't this mean that for loop of 100 should finish in the time of 1(since 100 threads save at the same time)?

Comment: And what if you set ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500, 100), also no difference? Also, database is local?

Comment: why do you await TestSave()?

Comment: it is the scenario that I am testing. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare performance of asynchronous code and parallel code. Asynchronous doesn't mean parallel. You can mix parallel code and asynchronous code however.

**Scenario 1 : Asynchronous code**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
 {
    await TestSave();
 }
```

For client applications, async code improves screen responsiveness . For server side, async code helps with scalability . For example , in asp.net when a request is received a thread pool thread is picked to handle that request. However, if request handling requires accessing an external resource such as getting some data from database, it will be just blocked doing nothing. Async code in this scenario will help return that thread to pool for processing any further request and they will return back to pick up where they had left previous request once external resource is available. As a result of this , server is able to process more requests then number of thread pools available to it.

**Scenario 2 : Parallel code**

```
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
                for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                {
                    tasks.Add(TestSave());

                }
  Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  or using Paralle.Foreach
```

In this case , TestSave will be executed in parallel on multiple Threads and hence the performance benefit.

Comment: I know what is Asynchronous and I know what is Parallel, and I know what I comparing. I don't know why I don't get expected performance for parallel code.Why is performance improvement so small in parallel case?